# position a div on top of an iframe in html

Tags: html, css

I'm struggling how to position a `<div>` on top of an `<iframe>` html tag.

So i have this iframe with a video in it. I created a `<div>` which holds the description of the vid and i want that div to be placed on top of the video/iframe.

I'm just not sure, how to properly set it up on CSS.

Also the player i'm using is a `type="application/x-google-vlc-plugin"`

```
...
<td>
    <div class="description"><h1>Title</h1></div>
    <iframe src="video.html" allowtransparency="yes"></iframe>
</td>
...
```

**[edit]**

this is my css

```
iframe { 
    width:480px; 
    height:300px;
    overflow:hidden; 
    border:0; 
    position:absolute; 
    z-index:-1; 
}

.description {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:999;
}
```

Comment: what result you get with this code?

Comment: Can you show the CSS you have so far?

Answer (score 0):

```
.description {
height:300px;
width:400px;
position:absolute;
top:0px;
left:0px;
z-index:10;
border-style:solid;
border-width:1px;
border-color:black;
}

iframe {
height:300px;
width:400px;
position:absolute;
top:0px;
left:0px;
z-index:1;
border-style:solid;
border-width:1px;
border-color:black;
}
```

Just change `border-width` to 0px when you get everything positioned where you want them.

Answer (score 0):

Give CSS Like this

```
iframe { 
    width:480px; 
    height:300px;
    overflow:hidden; 
    border:0; 
    position:relative; 

}

.description {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:999;
    width:480px; 
    height:300px
    top:0;
    left:0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd add a class to the `<td>` then give that `position: relative`. Then i'd just absolutely position both the`.description` and `iframe` inside of that. If you can give me an example `iframe` i will JSFiddle it for you